# Java code giving extra field in output

Tags: java, stdin

Below is my java code-

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {


    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = s.nextInt();  //number of test cases

    //aA1 b
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {

    String name = s.nextLine();

   System.out.println(name);

    String[] values = name.split("\\s");
   System.out.println(values.length);



    }


        s.close();
}
}
```

Below is my input from STDIN

```
3
aA1 b
a b c d
aa BB cc DD
```

Expected Output

```
aA1 b
2
a b c d
4
```

Original Output

```
1
aA1 b
2
a b c d
4
```

Why am I getting extra **1** in output?

I have tested in-https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php ?

Comment: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Comment: That isn't quite your output: there is actually an empty line before it, and that is significant.